# Quasi-random sequences: how to improve style and tests?

Tags: python, random

The requirements for this one were ([original SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4630723/555569)):

- Generate a random-ish sequence of items.
- Sequence should have each item N times.
- Sequence shouldn't have serial runs longer than a given number (longest below).

The solution was actually drafted by another user, this is [my implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4630723/using-python-for-quasi-randomization/4630784#4630784) (influenced by [random.shuffle](http://svn.python.org/view/python/trunk/Lib/random.py?view=markup#shuffle)).

```
from random import random
from itertools import groupby # For testing the result
try: xrange
except: xrange = range

def generate_quasirandom(values, n, longest=3, debug=False):
  # Sanity check
  if len(values) < 2 or longest < 1:
    raise ValueError

  # Create a list with n * [val]
  source = []
  sourcelen = len(values) * n
  for val in values:
    source += [val] * n

  # For breaking runs
  serial = 0
  latest = None

  for i in xrange(sourcelen):
    # Pick something from source[:i]
    j = int(random() * (sourcelen - i)) + i
    if source[j] == latest:
      serial += 1
      if serial >= longest:
        serial = 0
        guard = 0
        # We got a serial run, break it
        while source[j] == latest:
          j = int(random() * (sourcelen - i)) + i
          guard += 1
          # We just hit an infinit loop: there is no way to avoid a serial run
          if guard > 10:
            print("Unable to avoid serial run, disabling asserts.")
            debug = False
            break
    else:
      serial = 0
    latest = source[j]
    # Move the picked value to source[i:]
    source[i], source[j] = source[j], source[i]

  # More sanity checks
  check_quasirandom(source, values, n, longest, debug)

  return source


def check_quasirandom(shuffled, values, n, longest, debug):
  counts = []
  # We skip the last entries because breaking runs in them get too hairy
  for val, count in groupby(shuffled):
    counts.append(len(list(count)))
  highest = max(counts)
  print('Longest run: %d\nMax run lenght:%d' % (highest, longest))

  # Invariants
  assert len(shuffled) == len(values) * n
  for val in values:
    assert shuffled.count(val) == n

  if debug:
    # Only checked if we were able to avoid a sequential run >= longest
    assert highest <= longest

for x in xrange(10, 1000):
  generate_quasirandom((0, 1, 2, 3), 1000, x//10, debug=True)
```

I'd like to receive any input you have on improving this code, from style to comments to tests and anything else you can think of.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A couple of possible code improvements that I noticed:

```
sourcelen = len(values) * n
```

This seems unnecessarily complicated to me. I mean, after a second of thinking the reader of this line will realize that `len(values) * n` is indeed the length of `source`, but that's still one step of thinking more than would be required if you just did `sourcelen = len(source)` (after populating `source` of course).

That being said, I don't see why you need to store the length of `source` in a variable at all. Doing `for i in xrange(len(source)):` isn't really less readable or less efficient than doing `for i in xrange(sourcelen):`, so I'd just get rid of the variable altogether.

---

```
source = []
for val in values:
  source += [val] * n
```

This can be written as a list comprehension like this:

```
source = [x for val in values for x in [val]*n]
```

Using list comprehensions is usually considered more idiomatic python than building up a list iteratively. It is also often more efficient.

As Fred Nurk points out, the list comprehension can also be written as

```
source = [val for val in values for _ in xrange(n)]
```

which avoids the creation of a temporary list and is maybe a bit more readable.

---

```
j = int(random() * (sourcelen - i)) + i
```

To get a random integer between `x` (inclusive) and `y` (exclusive), you can use `random.randrange(x,y)`, so the above can be written as:

```
j = randrange(i, len(source) - i)
```

(You'll also need to import `randrange` instead of `random` from the random module). This makes it more immediately obviously that `j` is a random number between `i` and `len(source) - i` and introduces less room for mistakes.

Comment: Alternatively: `source = [val for val in values for _ in xrange(n)]` which, for me, makes it more clear you're repeating values compared to creating a temporary list, multiplying it, and then iterating it.